# Compilation error when inserting a figure with \usepackage{graphicx}

Tags: graphics, pdftex

I am trying to insert a figure into my report (using TexMaker), the code I'm using in the preamble is:

```
\usepackage{graphicx}
```

Then when placing my figure (which is a .png and located in the same folder as my .tex file) I have used this code:

```
\begin{figure}[htbp]
\centering
\includegraphics[scale=1]{BoneHier.png}
\caption{A figure depicting the hierarchical structure of bone from the macrostructure of compact and trabecular bone to the sub-nanostructure of the collagen fibrils and hydroxyapatite crystals. Figure taken from Rho, Kuhn-Spearing and Zioupos (1998)}
\end{figure}
```

When I compile under PDFLaTex this appears in my messages

```
!pdfTex error: pdflatex (file.BoneHier.png): libpng: internal error
==> fatal error occured, no output PDF file produced
```

EDIT: When I click "View PDF", I get an Error popping up saying "File not found"

(Sorry if this has been answered elsewhere, I have tried other solutions from other posts but they haven't worked!)

Comment: Why does your title say that you get a file not found error, and below you are writing about a libpng error?

Comment: Once I click "view PDF" it comes up with Error: File Not Found

Comment: Well naturally, you have an `fatal error occured, no output PDF file produced` error. So what should the viewer show?

Comment: Off topic: why it is necessary to add `scale=1`?

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Yes, that makes sense. I don't expect the pdf to form after the fatal error. I am confused as to what is causing the fatal error. Sorry if I am not being clear, I only downloaded TexMaker yesterday!

Comment: @JouleV I am unsure, this is what TexMaker codes when I insert a figure via the LaTex drop down and select \includegraphics{file}. I have tried [width=1\textwidth] too with the same outcome

Comment: @SammieDavies Of course, that is why I said "Off topic".

Comment: libpng error sounds as if the png is broken, but without access to the png it is difficult to say.

Comment: Does it work with other `.png` files? If yes, then the problem is with this file, it can for example be the case that it is actually a `.jpg` or some other file format and it was accidentally renamed as `.png`. (note that the image on https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S1350453398000071 from Rho et al. is a `.gif` image and not a `.png`, gif is not supported by LaTeX so you need to convert it first).

Comment: I've just screenshotted the figure and resaved as a .jpg and it worked! Thanks guys, you were all really helpful!